# Matchers.any() for null value in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

Suppose I am having this object `objectDemo` which calls to the method `objectDemoMethod` with 2 parameters `String` and `null`. Now I want to verify with Mockito that this method was called:

```
objectDemo.objectDemoMethod("SAMPLE_STRING", null);
```

I have written this:

```
Mockito.verify(objectDemo, Mockito.times(1)).objectDemoMethod(Matchers.any(String.class), null);
```

but it's giving an error:

> Invalid use of argument matchers for null value.

Is there any another way to pass `null` value?

Comment: quick side note: `Mockito.times(1)` is the default of `verify` and can be omitted.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The error message you are getting is expected since you are using argument matcher for only one argument and not the other. From [`Matchers`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html) Javadoc:

> If you are using argument matchers, **all arguments** have to be provided by matchers.

Therefore, the fix is to use a matcher for the second parameter of the method as well. In this case, it would be a matcher matching `null`. Depending on the version of Mockito and Java, you can have:

- Starting with Mockito 2, you can use [`ArgumentMatchers.isNull()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.1.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#isNull()). This works with Java 8 and above:

  ```
  verify(objectDemo, times(1)).objectDemoMethod(any(String.class), isNull());
  ```

  Note that if you're running with Java 7 or older, you'll need an explicit cast to make this work, because the type inference in those versions of Java does not take into account the types of the method called:

  ```
  verify(objectDemo, times(1)).objectDemoMethod(any(String.class), (String) isNull());
  ```
- If you're using Mockito 1, you can use the [`Matchers.isNull(clazz)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html#isNull(java.lang.Class)) instead:

  ```
  verify(objectDemo, times(1)).objectDemoMethod(any(String.class), isNull(String.class));
  ```

For the Java ≤ 7 or Mockito 1 cases, the examples uses a case where the second parameter was of type `String`: it would need to be replaced with the actual type of the method parameter.

Comment: UPDATES, we can use `nullable(String.class)` as `isNull(String.class)` considered deprecated now

Answer (score 42):

`isNull` seems to be deprecated

> With Java 8 this method will be removed in Mockito 3.0. This method is only used for generic friendliness to avoid casting, this is not anymore needed in Java 8.

I think you could use `nullable`:

- `public static <T> T nullable(Class<T> clazz)`

You could use something like:

```
verify(objectDemo, times(1)).objectDemoMethod(any(String.class), nullable(String.class));
```

Comment: To be clear, it's only `isNull(Class)` that's deprecated. `isNull()` is still there, and not going away anytime soon (at least, as of this writing).

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

`Mockito.verify(objectDemo, Mockito.times(1)).objectDemoMethod(Matchers.any(String.class), (ClassName) isNull());`

Above help me in java 8 version. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Mockito's ArgumentMatchers class, like so:

```java
Mockito.verify(objectDemo).objectDemoMethod(ArgumentMatchers.any(String.class), ArgumentMatchers.isNull());
```

Answer (score -1):

Ran into this when using Mockito 2.28 and Mockito Kotlin 2.2

`any()` and `isNull()` weren't matching. However, `eq(null)` did finally match, so you might try that if you're in the same boat.